# How can one deploy build artifacts from GitLab CI to an Azure app service?

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a repository hosted on gitlab.com, it has several build jobs associated with it. I would like for an ability to deploy the compiled artifacts of any given build (generally in the form of HTML/CSS/JavaScript compiled files) to azure.

All of the guides/docs/tutorials I've seen so far ([1](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/), [2](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/is-there-true-gitlab-azure-continuous-deployment/2162), [3](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment), to name a few), focus on deploying files directly from a git repository, which I can see being useful in some cases, but isn't what I need in this case, as I want the compilation targets, and not the source.

Solutions welcome, we've been bashing our heads over this for several days now.

Alternatives to GitLab in which this is made possible (in case it's not in GitLab), will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Add a deployment stage that has the build dependencies, from a job or more then a job, and thus downloads the artifacts of those jobs see below .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
- build
- ...
- deploy

buildjob:1:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build_to_web_dir.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - web

buildjob:2:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build_to_web_dir.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
     - web

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  GIT_STRATEGY: none
  image:  microsoft/azure-cli
  dependencies:
   - buildjob:1
   - buildjob:2
  script:
  - export containerName=mynewcontainername
  - export storageAccount=mystorageaccount
  - az storage blob delete-batch --source ${containerName} --account-name ${storageAccount} --output table
  - az storage blob upload-batch --source ./web --destination ${containerName} --account-name ${storageAccount} --output table --no-progress
```

In the deploy job, only one directory will be in the CI_PROJECT_DIR `./web` containing all files that the build jobs have produced.

checkout [storage quickstart azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/) for creating and setting up the storage container, account details etc.

For the deploy stage we can use the `microsoft/azure-cli` docker image, so we can call from our script the `az` command, see [storage-quickstart-blobs-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-cli) for more detail explanation.

```
az storage blob upload-batch --source ./web --destination ${containerName} --account-name ${storageAccount} --output blobname --no-progress
```

will copy ./web to the storage container

we should not export for security reasons in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="mystorageaccountname"
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY="myStorageAccountKey"
```

but they should be defined in the [project_or_group/settings/ci_cd](https://gitlab.com/gioxa/imagebuilder/settings/ci_cd) environment variables, so they'll be present in the script environment.

Comment: That "whatever method" is what I'm asking about tho

Comment: Updated with azure specifics

Comment: I'm not deploying to storage, I'm deploying to a webapp :) Therein lies the problem. It's either FTP or Git at least from what I see, one is slow and the other is impractical. I was hoping for an alternative I had missed, or some way to make deployment not suck.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, sorry don't understand. You have compiled your app resulting in the html/css/js, you upload to storage and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website to get it published on the web, the storage is the backend for the web.

Comment: No, I use a .NET IIS WebApp, not a storage. There's a C# backend on that webapp as well, and it needs access to the files to serve them (indirectly through a Web.config entry, or directly through a C# Web API controller)